# why is the CDB_QuantileBins function not found in cartoDB?

Tags: postgresql, sql, carto

What is wrong with the following SQL query on my data? I found pretty clear documentation ([1](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/wiki/CDB_QuantileBins),[2](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/advanced_concepts.html)) that the function is supposed to work.

```
SELECT CDB_QuantileBins(array_agg(numeric_column_of_mine), 10) from my_table
```

Comment: What is the *exact text* of the error message? Is the extension associated with this function installed in your database? Show the output of `\df *.CDB_QuantileBins` in `psql`. Mention any relevant versions. Please edit your question, comment here when done.

Comment: @CraigRinger I am not following, sorry. Can I query this (df) in the web interface as well? How exactly, sorry. But no, I did not install any extension, I thought this must work out-of-the box on the site.

Comment: Ah, you're using a PostgreSQL fork or some kind of canned service/extension (cartodb). Didn't spot that right away. Never mind. You should still show the *exact text* of the error message though.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a type inflexiblity in the function. Try this,

```
SELECT CDB_QuantileBins(array_agg(numeric_column_of_mine::numeric), 10) FROM my_table
```